# How to open navigation drawer with animation at startup

Tags: android, navigation

I implemented navigation drawer as described here in [android developer portal](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).
And everything works fine. Now I read android guidlines [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html). In section "Introduce the user to the drawer at first use" there is described I should open the drawer when application launches first. Now my idea for implementing this is to open the drawer after opening the app (and maybe close it again).

Now I tried to call myDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT) in onCreate and the drawer is open when the app launches, but there's no animation. So onCreate seems to be the wrong place. Where should I place the call to openDrawer to let the user see the animation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you can do this by delaying the animation. For example:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 

    myDrawer.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myDrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

However the fact that the Android Guidelines suggests the drawer to be opened when the application launches for the first time, does not imply it should be animated.

Comment: thanks, it works

and yes, you're true - it doesn't say it should be animated, but I think the user experience is better